# Python: Filter rows in data frame when multiple rows meet a unique condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a data set similar to:

```
    dt = {'A': [0,0,0,1], 
          'B': [0, 2,0,3],
          'C': [0,0,0,4],
          'D': [0,5,0,6]}
    dt = pd.DataFrame(dt)
```

I aim to filter all rows when columns ['A', 'B','C', 'D'] all are zero for that row. In real data set instead of 4 columns I have **more than twenty columns**. So the following solution is not feasible:

```
    dt = dt[(dt['A'] == 0) & (dt['B'] == 0) & (dt['C'] == 0) & (dt['D'] == 0)]
```

So I came up with the following solution:

```
    dt['new'] = np.nan
    lst = [0,1,2,3]

    for i in range(len(dt)):
        dt.iloc[i, 4] = all(dt.iloc[i, lst] == 0)
```

And finally I can filter based on 'new' column.

I am looking for a more efficient solution, preferably something without a loop, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this using [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with [`DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
dt[dt.eq(0).all(1)]

   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0
```

Another idea is to use [`np.any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) or [`DataFrame.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) as boolean mask

```
dt[~dt.any(1)] # @Sayandip Dutta's answer in the comments
dt[~np.any(dt, axis=1)]
```

Comment: Sure! That's why I didn't add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, [`DataFrame.sum(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)

```
dt[dt.sum(axis=1).eq(0)]
```

---

```
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0
```